# How can I run my React project on another machine?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webstorm

I am having a React project in WebStorm in my machine. I want to run it from another machine. I don't want to transfer the project file as it will cause dependency problems (dependencies which are installed in my machine in WebStorm). I want to have something like a build file which can run on another pc.

How can I do it?

Comment: Build it using Webpack or Browserify. Try them, and come back here when you have a problem.

Comment: I am new to this thing so can you please tell me how to do it exactly.

Comment: Please read the documentation [here](https://webpack.github.io/). It will take time to learn this. Full tutorial will be too long for an SO answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Let the machine you wish to use connect with your machine with code in local network.
2. Open the Run/Debug Configurations dialog. Enter JavaScript Debug. Click "Share" to switch on the share function.
3. Get the url that you debug on your machine. like

   localhost:63342/cocos2d-html5-v2.2.3/myproject/index.html
4. replace 'localhost' by your local network ip address. like

   192.168.199.160:63342/cocos2d-html5-v2.2.3/myproject/index.html
5. use the url above to access to your project.